# Jquery read letters in row major order concentrate them into a single string and return it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

During my job interview i had task to create a function using jquery which read letters from a table in row major order concentrate them into a single string and return it. but it must skip letters that have the same color and background color. I failed it but I want to fix the problem anyway . Can You help me with this? i used function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  let para = $('th').toArray();
 
  $.map(para, function (i) {
    if ($(i).css('color') !== $(i).css('background-color')) {
      newStr = '';
      newStr = $(i).text();

    
      return newStr;
    }
  });
```

here is html code:

```
<body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th style="background-color: blue; color: yellow">Q</th>
          <th style="background-color: magenta; color: yellow">A</th>
          <th style="background-color: green; color: green">M</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="background-color: green; color: magenta">P</th>
          <th style="background-color: red; color: red">A</th>
          <th style="background-color: yellow; color: green">Q</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I guess you are emptying the `newStr` on each iteration of your map. Should be `newStr +=` and `newStr` should be decleared outside of the `map` - Also where would you  return the `newStr` ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping just to be sure, as all the elements, are having different colors, AND backgrounds, all must be concatenated, right?

Comment: @PranavRustagi No. only four should be concatenated - Two elements in the table have same color and same bg.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```js
var str = "";

$('th').each(function() {
  if ($(this).css("color") != $(this).css("background-color")) {
    str += $(this).text();
  }
});

console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="background-color: blue; color: yellow">Q</th>
      <th style="background-color: magenta; color: yellow">A</th>
      <th style="background-color: green; color: green">M</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="background-color: green; color: magenta">P</th>
      <th style="background-color: red; color: red">A</th>
      <th style="background-color: yellow; color: green">Q</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: that way too much complicated pranav. the code above in the question is solved already. just put `newStr = ''` outside the map and add `+` as  `newStr +=` in the map. Same results

Comment: @AlwaysHelping sorry! I am not acquainted with `map` at present. I am still learning. Will definitely learn :)

Comment: No problem :) Nice effort though :)  - here is what i am talking about in my comments = https://jsfiddle.net/w1x2p3s5/

Comment: @AlwaysHelping check it again... It's shorter now. Actually I performed column major in previous one.